# Problem with Entity Framework 6 migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, database-migration

I have a problem with creating migration for Entity Framework 6 in code first approach. I already created migration, but later when I tried to create new, this was the errror:

> Your target project 'Blog' doesn't reference EntityFramework. This
> package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work.
> Ensure your target project is correct, install the package, and try
> again.

I checked NuGet, EF6 is installed, alongside with these packages[image]

Comment: Can you provide the PM command you were executing?

Comment: "Entity Framework Core" is different from "Entity Framework 6". You should use "ef6.exe" or "Add-Migration" command if you are using EF6